# PHP dropdown list

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get the user to pick from the dropdown menu. When the user clicks on the selected item they will click a button and show the results.
I haven't been able to display the information onto the page.

```
$sql = "select * from Owner";
echo'<form action="index1.php" method="post">';
echo '<select name="bid" id="bid">';

    foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<option value=" ';
        echo $row["id"];
        echo ' ">';
        echo $row['LastName'];
        echo '</option>';
    }
echo'</select>';

echo'<br><input type="submit" value="Show Info"><br>';
echo'</form>';

//check if submit button has been clicked
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $id = $_POST['bid'];
    try{
        $sql = "select Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName,MarinaSlip.BoatName from Owner, MarinaSlip where Owner.OwnerNum = MarinaSlip.OwnerNum 
                and Owner.FirstName = $id";
        foreach($coon->query($sql) as $row){
            echo$row['FirstName'].' '.$row['LastName'].' '.$row['BoatName'].'<br>';
        }
    }//end of try
    catch(PDOExeption $e){
        echo "Error: ".$e -> getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: May not be your problem, but looks like you have a typo in `$coon->query`.

Comment: Yes it was a typo. Just checked but didn't work. Thanks for spotting the typo

Comment: Are you seeing any errors while debugging?

Comment: No i haven't seen any errors.

Comment: There's another typo: `echo$row`, seems you're missing a space there.